# search for data from a list in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

my database looks like:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('3f05e2aa794e17504a6674a7'),  
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('6f05e2aa794e177b456674a9'), 'name': 'text1'}, 
    {'_id': ObjectId('2f05e2aa794e1765286674a8'),'name': 'text3', }
    ]
}

{'_id': ObjectId('3f05e3aa791e17f23b6674aa'), 
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('7f05e2aa494e17f5b36674ac'), 'name': 'text12'}, 
    {'_id': ObjectId('5f05e2aa794e1707006674ab'), 'name': 'text2'}
    ]
}
```

also i have a list

`lists =["6f05e2aa794e177b456674a9", "2f05e2aa794e1765286674a8", "5f05e2aa794e1707006674ab"]`

I need to find only those objects and their names that are in the list

```
`{
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('6f05e2aa794e177b456674a9'), 'name': 'text1'}, 
    {'_id': ObjectId('2f05e2aa794e1765286674a8'),'name': 'text3', }
    ]
}
{
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('5f05e2aa794e1707006674ab'), 'name': 'text2'}
    ]
}
```

I wrote a query that worked for one value

```
id = "6f05e2aa794e177b456674a9"
objInstance = ObjectId(id)

fx = mycol.find(
    { "lt": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": objInstance }}},
    { "lt": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": objInstance }},
     "_id":0, "lt._id":1 , "lt.name":1}
  ).limit(5)

maydata=[]

for x in fx:
    print(x)
```

but when I rewrote it for list search

```
lists =["6f05e2aa794e177b456674a9", "2f05e2aa794e1765286674a8", "5f05e2aa794e1707006674ab"]
obj_ids = list(map(lambda x: ObjectId(x), lists))


fx = mycol.find(
    { "lt": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": {"$in" : obj_ids }}}},
    { "lt": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": {"$in": obj_ids }}},
     "_id":0, "lt._id":1 , "lt.name":1}
  ).limit(5)


maydata=[]

for x in fx:
    print(x)
```

it returned me only one element of the document

```
{
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('2f05e2aa794e1765286674a8'),'name': 'text3', }
    ]
}
{
'lt': [
    {'_id': ObjectId('5f05e2aa794e1707006674ab'), 'name': 'text2'}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate pipeline using `$filter` like this:

This query project the result using `$project` showing only the values into `lt` that are also into your array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "lt": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$lt",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$this._id",
              obj_ids
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SuwKkqLheaY)